# Non-linear backward Kolmogorov equation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, statistical-mechanics

The backward Kolmogorov equation (BKE):
$$\frac{du}{dt} = A(x,t) \cdot \nabla_x u(x,t) -\frac12 \text{Tr}(BB^t(x,t) \text{Hess}_x u(x,t) - f(t,x,u, B,\nabla g), \;\;\; t<T$$

If $f\equiv 0$ then this is a linear BKE. I read that if a BKE is linear, then there exists a corresponding stochastic process $X(t)$ whose probability density is the solution of the BKE, and $X(t)$ solves the stochastic differential equation
$$dX(t) = A(X(t),t) dt + B(X(t)),t)dW(t).$$

Now, if the BKE is non-linear, when does a corresponding stochastic process exist? For example, the Allen-Cahn equation is a non-linear BKE. How do we find the corresponding stochastic process?

Comment: If you add a non-linear forcing term, then the differantial operator cannot be the generator of a diffusion process.

Comment: @Tobsn Wow, why is that?

Comment: Because generators are by definition linear operators.

Comment: @Tobsn oh okay... then is there some generalization of "markov generator of a diffusion process" that can correspond to a non-linear differential operator?

Comment: @Tobsn for example I have seen some control theory problems whose "diffusion limit" is a non-linear PDE. the discrete control theory problem maybe is non-Markovian. Could this be where the non-linearity arises?

Comment: None, that I'm aware of. Anyway, that a PDE is not associated to a Markov generator, doesn't mean that there can be no stochastic representation for the solution. Measure-valued branching processes, e.g.,  have natural link to non-linear reaction-diffusion equations.

Comment: @Tobsn what is it about those processes that make the diffusion equation non-linear? Is it something about interaction? For example iid random walks give the usual diffusion but if we make the stepping probabilities dependent on their position or nearby particles, would this make the hydrodynamic limit a nonlinear diffusion?